# Storage Spaces Direct MTBF

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces, fault-tolerance

I'm testing S2D now and I would like to calculate MTBF for the whole system. It seems very fragile to me:

Let's have 4 nodes (x) with 12 drives (y) in each. MTBF for one node is `1/12` of single drive value. For three-copy mirror we can tolerate  2 node failures (equals two failed disks in different nodes). That gives me `2/4` MTBF of single node value. In total it is `1/24` or `2/(x*y)` MTBF in comparison to single drive.

This value is quite low and gets even lower for larger deployments. Is my calc correct? I know that Microsoft recommends to reserve capacity of 2 disks in the pool aka hot-spares, but is it sufficient for production use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft recommends % of usable capacity, "2 disks" is too bold statement for say 90 disk JBOD.